# geth sync stuck at 2,700,000

Tags: synchronization

It all ran well before 2,700,000 but when comes above 2,700,000 hellish...

```
INFO [12-21|00:08:43.253] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=
5  mgas=0.356 elapsed=30.309s   mgasps=0.012 number=2701160 hash=30bcc0be60e8 ag
e=3y1mo1w dirty=40.46MiB
WARN [12-21|00:09:36.784] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=2ad507adee
2cdf47 conn=dyndial addr=51.83.96.188:30305    type=Getc/v6.0.9/linux/go1.12.9
WARN [12-21|00:10:19.192] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=2ad507adee
2cdf47 conn=dyndial addr=51.83.96.188:30305    type=Getc/v6.0.9/linux/go1.12.9
INFO [12-21|00:12:41.838] Imported new chain segment               blocks=3 txs=
12 mgas=2.535 elapsed=3m58.585s mgasps=0.011 number=2701163 hash=6892b15d491b ag
e=3y1mo1w dirty=45.25MiB
WARN [12-21|00:14:44.929] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=2ad507adee
2cdf47 conn=dyndial addr=51.83.96.188:30305    type=Getc/v6.0.9/linux/go1.12.9
INFO [12-21|00:15:31.450] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=
2  mgas=1.162 elapsed=2m49.611s mgasps=0.007 number=2701164 hash=1a3c0c06fe7e ag
e=3y1mo1w dirty=47.79MiB
WARN [12-21|00:16:22.281] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=63cbc31e70
27052b conn=dyndial addr=47.111.121.250:30303  type=Geth/v1.9.10-unstable-d90d1d
b6-20191210/linux-amd64/go1.13.5
WARN [12-21|00:17:03.571] Checkpoint challenge timed out, dropping id=2ad507adee
2cdf47 conn=dyndial addr=51.83.96.188:30305    type=Getc/v6.0.9/linux/go1.12.9
INFO [12-21|00:19:41.046] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=
9  mgas=2.472 elapsed=4m9.596s  mgasps=0.010 number=2701166 hash=977c882c2768 ag
e=3y1mo1w dirty=52.55MiB
```

Just take a look... few minutes a single block I can't live to that day lol

How is that happening? It goes all well before

(using full sync)